# Mongo db Node js multipuple count queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am making an app with nodejs, express and mongodb and I have the following issue. I want to make multipuple count queries using geospatial data (e.g. find how many documents are within the borders of a usa state). The problem is that when I am just making a simple for loop (for all the states) at the end all that I can see is the result of the last query and nothing more. I realize that this is an issue of the asynchronous way javascript works but I cannot find a way to solve the issue. My code right now looks like the following based on a code I've found on stack. Note that statesData is an object containing usa states data.

```
for(var i=0; i<51; i++){
    increment = function(request, callback) {   
        var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
            format = require('util').format;
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/DBNAME', function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var collection = db.collection('ColName');
            collection.count({PLACE: {
               $geoWithin: {
                  $geometry: {
                     type : statesData.features[i].geometry.type ,
                     coordinates: statesData.features[i].geometry.coordinates,
                  }
               }
             }
            }, function(err, count) {
                if (err) throw err;                                     
                db.close();

                console.log("docs count: " + count);     
                callback(null, count);   
            });       
       });                 
    };

    increment({}, function(err, count) {
       console.log(count);
    });
}
```

Comment: The for-loop is blocking, i.e. it is not asynchronous. You need an asynchronous-friendly version of looping, try Node.js 'async' module: `http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#whilst` i.e. `var count = 0;
async.whilst(
    function() { return count < 51; },
    function(callback) { ... })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `for` statement by an `async` statement like :

```
var async = require('async');
var i = 0;
var counts = [];

async.whilst(
    function () {
        return i < 51;
    },
    function (callback) {
        i++;

        var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
        var format = require('util').format;

        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/DBNAME', function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var collection = db.collection('ColName');

            collection.count({
                PLACE: {
                    $geoWithin: {
                        $geometry: {
                            type : statesData.features[i].geometry.type ,
                            coordinates: statesData.features[i].geometry.coordinates,
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, function(err, count) {
                if (err) throw err;     

                db.close();

                console.log("docs count: " + count);     

                // you shouyld save your count value in a clojure var like :
                counts.push(count);

                callback(null, i);
            });       
        });              
    },
    function () {
        // final callback

        // here, you should launch the final callback to get all counts values
        console.log(counts);
    }
});
```